# MISRA C:2012 Rule 14.3

Tags: c, misra

I am confused how to resolve MISRA 2012 14.3:

> The condition in `if`, `for`, `while`, `do`-`while`, or ternary operator will never be true.

I am having code like this:

```
uint8 Func1(int a)
{
#if (SOME_MARCO == ON)
    return (a == somevalue ) ? 0u : 1u;
#else
    return 0u;
#endif
}

void main()
{
    if (Func1 == ou)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If the `MARCO` is not defined, then I get a warning at line `if (Func1 == ou)`, conditional expression always true.

I do not know how to resolve this issue since the `marco` has real meaning, and I can't remove it. I wonder what should I do to resolve warning like this?

/***************************************************************/

edit:
Sorry about the typo and pseudo code.

The real code is :

```
uint8_t ucDetectionCheckAccStatus( void )
{
#if ( ACC_DETECTION == STD_ON )
    if ( Dio_ReadChannel( detectionDIO_CHANNEL_ACC ) == DETECTION_LEVEL_ACC_NORMAL )
    {
        return detectionSTATE_NORMAL;
    }
    else
    {
        return detectionSTATE_ABNORMAL;
    }
#else
    return detectionSTATE_NORMAL;
#endif
}

bool xDetectionCheckForNormal(void)
{
...
    if( ucDetectionCheckAccStatus( ) ==(uint8_t)detectionSTATE_ABNORMAL )
        {
            return false;
        }
...
}
```

And thanks for all the answers, I think I can try to do the conditional compile in xDetectionCheckForNormal to avoid this? Or there is a better way?

Comment: Is "ou" supposed to be "0u"?  Is "MARCO" supposed to be "MACRO"?  Macros like this do sometimes produce constant functions.  In my view, the best answer is to use a pragma to suppress the warning.

Comment: You could try putting `#if ( SOME_MARCO != ON)` / `#endif` around that `if`, so that when the condition is always true, there isn't a condition any more - just a block of code.

Comment: Did you mean to write `if (Func1() == 0u)`?  Right now it compares the address of function `Func1` to an undefined variable `ou`, without calling the function.

Comment: What is `somevalue`? Is it a compile-time constant? Please post the real code instead of incomplete pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is not about the constant value returned by `Func1`, but about the fact that you compare `Func1` with `ou`, (presumably `0u`) and this test is always false because `Func1` is a function so its address cannot be null.

You forgot the `()` for the function to be called instead of its address to be used in the expression.

Also note that the prototype for `main` without arguments should be `int main(void)`.

Here is a modified version:

```
uint8 Func1(int a)
{
#if (SOME_MACRO == ON)
    return (a == somevalue ) ? 0u : 1u;
#else
    return 0u;
#endif
}

int main(void)
{
    if (Func1(0) == 0u)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, the _Func1()_ actually needs a parameter, as in _Func1(4)_

Comment: `void main (void)` is a common form in embedded ("freestanding") systems where you are most likely to encounter MISRA C. I wouldn't recommend changing it without any context.

Comment: @virolino: good point! answer amended.

Comment: @Lundin: you are correct. There may be special rules for some environments that allow or call for system specific alternatives, but in many cases, `void main()` is just a classic beginner mistake.